# How to set timeout for the request Vision.Images.Annotate

Tags: java, google-apis-explorer

I am using below code to call google cloud vision api. not able to find out how can I set response timeout for the request in case I do not get response within a set timeout.

```
Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
                vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);
// Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
annotateRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
Log.d(TAG, "created Cloud Vision request object, sending request");

BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageAnnotatorSettings.Builder to set timeout value

```
    final ImageAnnotatorSettings.Builder imageAnnotatorSettingsBuilder =
            ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder();
    imageAnnotatorSettingsBuilder.batchAnnotateImagesSettings().getRetrySettings().toBuilder()
            .setTotalTimeout(org.threeten.bp.Duration.ofSeconds(45))
            .setMaxAttempts(1);
final ImageAnnotatorSettings imageAnnotatorSettings = imageAnnotatorSettingsBuilder.build();
    ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create(imageAnnotatorSettings)
```